# How to Fix 'mvn: command not found' Error When Installing Apache Maven 3.0.5?

Tags: maven, macos-high-sierra

How to install Maven on an older version of Macbook HighSierra 10.13.6?

1.) First step - Path to the downloaded path (apache-maven-3.0.5):
[image]

2.)create file .bash_profile with resources
[image]

[image]

3.)trying to run mvn version
[image]

4.)run command: brew install maven
[image]

[image]

What is the possibility?

Comment: Download most recent version of Maven and follow the guide for installation... it does not matter that you are on an older version of MacOS... the only things you need is at least JDK8 to run most recent version of Maven..